# lat_0, lon_0 ignored by Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to set up Basemap to use a Cylindrical Equal Area projection and to place the origin at a specific lat/lon (this is to match some input x/y data), but it seems that setting the `lat_0` and `lon_0` parameters does nothing.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# Oklahoma bounds 
# ('o' = origin at corner of Kingfisher/Logan/Canadian/Oklahoma counties)
lats = {'n':  37.1, 's':  33.6,  'c':  35.5, 'o':  35.726}
lons = {'e': -94.4, 'w': -103.0, 'c': -97.5, 'o': -97.674}

buf = 0.05 # plot buffer size (in degrees)

res = 'c' # map shapes resolution

# projection parameters
proj = 'cea' # cylindrical equal area
lat_ts = lats['c'] # true scale at geographic center
lon_0 = lons['o']  # x=0 at counties corner
lat_0 = lats['o']  # y=0 at counties corner

m = Basemap(projection = proj, lat_ts = lat_ts, resolution = res,
            lon_0 = lon_0, lat_0 = lat_0,
            urcrnrlon = lons['e'] + buf, urcrnrlat = lats['n'] + buf,
            llcrnrlon = lons['w'] - buf, llcrnrlat = lats['s'] - buf*4)
```

Then checking the origin gives:

```
In [15]: m(0, 0, inverse=True)
Out[15]: (-103.05000000000305, 33.399999999963455)
```

...which is the lower-left corner of the map bounds, not the coordinates I gave for `lat_0` and `lon_0`. I get the same output if I leave out lat_0 and lon_0 entirely.

At first, I thought maybe the CEA projection doesn't support these parameters and that I should just shift my data manually, but [the docs claim that `lat_0` and `lon_0` are used by all projections](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html).

As a workaround, I can set an offset to get the intended results:

```
offset = m(lon_0, lat_0)
df['x'], df['y'] = (df.x + offset[0], df.y + offset[1]) # where df is a Pandas dataframe with my data
```

I have now submitted this as an issue on the Basemap GitHub repository.
https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/192

Comment: I've noticed this as well. In particular note that the docs say `lat_0 : central latitude (y-axis origin) - used by all projections.` And similar for `lon_0`.

Comment: In my opinion this is a real bug. You may want to consider moving this to https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues.

Comment: I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something before claiming a bug. If no one has anything else to add, I'll make a ticket.